# How to parse internal JSON elements?

Tags: java, json

I'm using `json-simple-1.1.1.jar` which was referred by tutorialpoint.com.

My JSON file is shown here:

[image: JSON structure]

My java code is here:

[image: my code]

I couldn't understand how I would access `"onclick": "CloseDoc()"` in my JSON file.

If I use the `getObject` method it is showing me an error:

> The method getJSONObject(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject

Comment: hi jhanvi, i'm working on java not java script.

Comment: Could you include your code in the question plz?

Comment: plz check the above links in the question. It not allowing me to post code so uploaded my screen shots.

Comment: which lib are you using?

Comment: json-simple-1.1.1.jar from https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could check the import is **org.json.simple.JSONObject**
but this jar is not had a method call getJsonObject.

Comment: Dont post comments as answers

Comment: i just post my check result , and i will edit my content.
it may import wrong jar , or poster want to use the method is undefined in jar.

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` is inside the array `menuitem` which is inside the object `menu` , so you have to loop the array to retrieve what you want. You can try it like this:

```
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String json_str = obj.toString();
        JSONObject j_org_json_obj = new JSONObject(json_str);
        JSONArray j_org_json_arr = j_org_json_obj.getJSONObject("menu").getJSONArray("menuitem");
        for(int i=0;i<j_org_json_arr.length();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(j_org_json_arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("onClick()"));
        }
```

Along with [json-simple jar](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) ,In the above code one more jar is included : [org-json jar](https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/detail?name=org.json-20120521.jar&can=2&q=) , so import that as well.

Comment: The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined at line 4 and i added org-json jar

Comment: what are the imports you are using??